# How to rename all .jpg files in all subdirs which contains dash in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, rename, bulk

I have subfolders with dashes (example subdir with name **c-d**). I need to rename all .jpg files with all subdirs, any tips how to do it?

I've tried many option, but nothing helped (I think because my subfolders contains dashes **-**)

Comment: Show us what you have done so far please so we can help you

Comment: What is your pattern for renaming files? What are original names and what do you want to get?

Comment: I'm tried find -name '*.jpg' -exec rename $RANDOM.jpg $RANDOM.jpg {} \; 
but getting
(Missing operator before jpg?)
syntax error at (user-supplied code) line 3, near "2635.jpg"
Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 4) line 1, near "#line 1
2635.jpg"

Comment: What do you mean "rename all .jpg files with all subdirs"? If the file is `./a-b/c-d/e.jpg` what should the new name be?

Comment: New name can be whatever name. It can be just random [0-9].jpg.
I have folder A with subfolders a-a b-b c-c. Each subfolder contains .jpg image. I want rename all this .jpg in all subfolders

Comment: In example this script can rename only in current folder for i in *.jpg; do mv $i $RANDOM.jpg; done
But how i can rename .jpg files in all subfolders?

Comment: There is absolutely no guarantee that your generated filenames will be unique. You may lose data. Also, this is really unclear and arbitrary; is it a homework assignment? How about an example of what you've tried? Try reading over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first.

Answer (score 0):

`$RANDOM` can get you collisions.  Let's use the md5 checksum hashes instead since they're random-looking yet determined by the content (meaning the only collisions will be when you have identical files anyway).

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
  mv "$file" "${file%/*}/$( md5sum "$file" |awk '{print $1}' )".jpg
done < <(find . -name '*.jpg' -print0)
```

This takes the md5 checksum of each file's contents and renames the file to it, preserving the directory structure and a trailing `.jpg`

This looks a bit ugly due to needing to preserve spaces.

Running `while IFS=` loops over contents with no input field separator (`$IFS`). Each iteration calls `read -r -d '' file`, which reads in content delimited by a null character while ignoring backslash escapes and stores entries in a variable called `$file`.

Skipping to the end of the loop, you can see it iterating on the null-terminated output of a `find` command that looks for files named `*.jpg`.  This is performed via [Bash process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) in order to prevent scoping issues with a subshell created by a standard pipe (more detail can be found in [BashFAQ/020](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020), which I adapted for this problem).

Inside the loop, we have the actual rename action, which uses [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) to run `md5sum` on the file and then clean it up with `awk` (which is told to print only the first field, which is the checksum).  The directory structure is preserved by [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), where `${file%/*}` strips the last slash and all trailing non-slash characters so we can append the hash and then `.jpg` to the new file name.  (This is the same as `$(dirname "$file")` but without the system call.)

If you really want random numbers and you don't care about collisions, replace `$( md5sum "$file" |awk '{print $1}' )` with `$RANDOM`.  If you give `mv` the `-i` option, it will prompt you in the event of a collision in the same directory.

This will not work in POSIX shells or other basic shells due to nonstandard flags in `read` and the process substitution.  You can probably use `mkfifo` and/or `xargs -0` to work around that, but that's not going to be easy.